# Absolutely eliminate "Automatic new Desktop when dragging"

Tags: mojave, spaces

- As far as I know I do have only one (1) Desktop enabled
- I'm looking at this web page right now in **Safari**.
- Safari is a normal window (say, 50% of the width and height of the physical screen, and it is sitting right in the middle of the physical screen).
- This is a mid 2015 mbp with no external monitors attached.  Every piece of software is the latest as of writing
- Using the pointer, I grab an image (say, one of the small icons on this screen).
- I **grag** it to the extreme right of the desktop - as if I am going to drop it on the desktop near the right
- But I keep dragging it, and hold it on the extreme right edge of the screen

## IN FACT WHAT HAPPENS IS......

- After a few moments, the "whole desktop" **will slide to a new desktop** on the "right".
- Strangely, this new desktop has a different color background to my usual desktop
- The "new" Desktop appears to be identical to my usual only desktop (same icons scattered around etc), except only the background color is different

## And click here for a video !!!

http://tinypic.com/r/jq2nis/9

I want to completely disable this "sliding" function.  *(Or at least know what the hell it is!!)* Is it possible?

Related!  [How do I correctly set strictly ONLY ONE desktop?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344403/how-do-i-correctly-set-strictly-only-one-desktop)

Comment: Not seeing this behavior. I have several desktops enabled, yes macOS will happily slide to the next available if I drag a file/window to the extreme right of the screen, but it won't create NEW desktops. Once I hit #4 (the last desktop I have enabled) holding a file against the right side of the screen doesn't trigger any action. Perhaps you have more than 1 screen enabled in Mission Control? Remove them, it should not auto-create more.

Comment: That's amazing info @dr.nixon , thanks.   You should really put it in as an answer so I can bounty you.  I added further clarification, pls look!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not seeing this behavior. I have several desktops enabled, yes macOS will happily slide to the next available if I drag a file/window to the extreme right of the screen, but it won't create NEW desktops. Once I hit #4 (the last desktop I have enabled) holding a file against the right side of the screen doesn't trigger any action. Perhaps you have more than 1 screen enabled in Mission Control? Remove them, it should not auto-create more. (added as answer per request!)

Comment: Could be entirely possible. You aren't by chance running Safari in full-screen mode are you? Because in recent macOS versions, full screen runs in a separate Space by default...

Comment: ^^ Just to be clear, "recent" in this case means "Since version 10.7 Lion", which I wouldn't personally consider all that new anymore.

Comment: @dr.nixon it SEEMS ?? I have only one enabled??   https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344403/how-do-i-correctly-set-strictly-only-one-desktop   ?!!

Comment: Solved!   I had 400 desktops !!   thank you so much, @dr.nixon . Really thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your problems are related to some settings and an *habit*. Lat's take them separately:

1) Settings:

To have on and only one desktop, proceed as follows:
a) Open System Preferences and select Mission Control tab. Please see in the lower left corner the button labeled **Hot Corners** and click on it. You will get something similar to this picture below:

[image]

For hot corners configured as active, you will get some labels as seen for the upper right corner in my picture. 
Click on blue control marked with arrows, and a scrolling list will open, like in the picture below:

[image]

Now select the minus sign (-), the last on that list and click OK button. You will have **one and only one desktop** if all hot corners are marked with minus sign.

2) About *habit*

Seems to me that when you drag to the right, you accidentally touch the + button which add a new desktop. See the picture below:

So, try to avoid the regions declared as "hot corners" when dragging.

However, if you still need another desktop, add "Mission Control" for the right hot corner. Moving the mouse to the upper right you can add a new desktop. But moving a window to the right will not open a new desktop.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic description, just for clarity: when you write: *"Seems to me that when you drag to the right, you accidentally touch the + button..."*  when you say "+ button", what do you mean?  In fact do you mean(A)  the "+ hot corner" ?   (B) the + button on the laptops's physical keyboard  (C) another + button I don't know about, whether virtual or physical!!    :)   THANKS!!  Fantastic stuff

Comment: @Fattie, I mean the A) - the + for add a new desktop. See it on the last picture, inside the white circle. When adding/dragging a window, this could be masked by that, so be careful.

Comment: Got it!   I will be absolutely sure that it is turned off (per part 1 of your explanation), and indeed, now I will know it is happening if (for some reason or the other) it is turned on and I drag to that area!   FANTASTIC !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

In the Dock you can also assign your apps to "All Desktops".

Answer (score 1):

Refering to http://osxdaily.com/2010/02/10/change-the-delay-when-dragging-windows-within-spaces/ ,

instead of using a smaller delay, you could try to use **a very large delay**.

I haven't tested it. Please report the result.

PS: I tried that if there is **only one** Desktop, it won't 'slide to next'.

Comment: fascinating link !

Answer (score -2):

It turns out for some reason I had

## about 400 desktops

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/344432/19991

It seems that when you have more than "a hundred" or so the interface becomes so confusing, I didn't even know I had 2 desktops.

- This seems to entirely explain the problem, but
- It remains a mystery why I had 400 desktops.
- I still don't get how to completely turn off this desktops feature, but, that's life

When you do have only 1x desktop, then as Dr.Nixon reports the problem I describe indeed does not happen.

Phew