# How do I correctly set strictly only one desktop?

Tags: finder, mojave, spaces

With Desktops, you can have more than one Desktop.

I want to assign absolutely only one Desktop, not two.

How do I do this exactly?

---

When I click F3, it looks like this:

[image]

(Does that mean I have only one?)

---

Resolved!

Buscar웃 has identified the issue.  I manually deleted the 400 desktops and now this issue:

[Absolutely eliminate "Automatic new Desktop when dragging"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343598/absolutely-eliminate-automatic-new-desktop-when-dragging/344440#344440)

is finally resolved.

Comment: did you try, Press F3, hover over desktop window, click the x to delete it.

Comment: thanks for that great tip to begin with!  I will edit ...

Comment: I had no idea about F3 - thanks for that.   There does see to be ONLY ONE desktop - is that right?  Notice the white square in the posted image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is amazing.

You have created so many desktops that macOS can only display them as a dot.

That line of dots represents your desktops. I did not count but it must be more than 50.

How to delete them.

Press F3

Hold Option Key and keep clicking on the **X** showing to delete them.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH - I will get on this and get back to you ..

Comment: It really takes a long time.  250 so far.

Comment: I stopped counting at about 300.  I guess about 400.  It is really hard to delete that many due to the silly animatio which doesn't align.  **You're a lifesaver**.  Now to figure out what was going on.   Maybe itrelates to using two monitors??

Comment: That is a good question. "Why do I have hundreds of Desktops" ? post it as separate question.

Answer (score 2):

To your second separate question

> Why do I have hundreds of Desktops

Open System preference > Mission Control.

Un-check the `Displays have separate Spaces`.

That should stop it creating new Desktops.

[image]

Comment: Done; in fact it was off.  Could be, in the past I had it turned on, and, for some reason the Desktops built up then.  I will see what happens going forward!  Thanks!

Comment: OK, lets see, at least now you are starting new